# ZOD conditional validation based on sibling's value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I'm working with a validation schema using Zod, where I have an items field that represents an object that has a field of type array but this field can be null based on the value of its sibling field. I'm not able to validate this conditional using `superRefine()` method.

Providng an example schema below:

**Schema :-**

```
const schema = z.object({
  type: z.enum(['type1', 'type2'])
  // if type is type1, value should be null
  value: z.object({value1: z.number(), value2: z.number()}).nullable() 
}).superRefine((item, refinementContext) => {
  if(item.type === 'type2' && !item.value) {
    refinementContext.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
      message: 'Provide a valid value.',
      path: ['value'],
    })
  }
})
```

**Default Value:**

```
const default: SchemaType = {
  type: 'type1',
  value: null
}
```

Since, I'm providing value as nullable, I'm not getting the error even if type is `type2`.

What am I doing wrong here?